# Css overflow hidden outside

Tags: css, overflow

I hace this structure for create 2 cols and inside content :

```
        <style>
    #articulos_content
        {
        position:relative;
        width:100%;
        min-height:400px;
        height:auto;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        margin-bottom:30px;
        overflow:hidden;
        }

        #articulos_load_col_left
        {
        float:left;
        position:relative;  
        width:72%;
        mini-height:400px;
        height:auto;
        margin-bottom:-50000px;
        padding-bottom:50000px;
        }

        #articulos_load_col_right
        {
        float:right;
        position:relative;  
        width:28%;
        mini-height:400px;
        height:auto;
        background-color:#cccccc;
        margin-bottom:-50000px;
        padding-bottom:50000px;
        }
</style>

<div id="articulos_content">
<div id="articulos_load_col_left">Load the articles in bucle</div>
<div id="articulos_load_col_right"></div>
</div>
```

How you can see the style called articulos_content have 2 divs working as cols , and in the col left i load bucle in php for show articles

I have problem with overflow hidden in the style called articulos_content , because the articles have popup for show article´s comments , and the overflow hidden cut this css-window and no let me see all , but overflow:hidden it´s necessary for grow the cols and in this point i don´t know what can i do for fix this problem

Thank´s

Answer (score 0):

use a clearfix as extra class. where ever you are using overflow, remove over flow addclass clearfix to that div it will work.

```
.clearfix:after {
 content: " "; /* Older browser do not support empty content */
 visibility: hidden;
 display: block;
 height: 0;
 clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Sorry don´t understand how i can do this , thank´s :)

Answer (score 0):

As mention by @Venu immadi add "clearfix" as a class in your container,  and add the style in your css.

See below:

```
<style>
    #articulos_content
    {
        position:relative;
        width:100%;
        min-height:400px;
        height:auto;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        margin-bottom:30px;
        overflow:hidden;
    }

    #articulos_load_col_left
    {
        float:left;
        position:relative;  
        width:72%;
        mini-height:400px;
        height:auto;
        margin-bottom:-50000px;
        padding-bottom:50000px;
    }

    #articulos_load_col_right
    {
        float:right;
        position:relative;  
        width:28%;
        mini-height:400px;
        height:auto;
        background-color:#cccccc;
        margin-bottom:-50000px;
        padding-bottom:50000px;
    }

    .clearfix:after 
    {
         content: " "; /* Older browser do not support empty content */
         visibility: hidden;
         display: block;
         height: 0;
         clear: both;
    }

</style>

<div id="articulos_content" class="clearfix">
    <div id="articulos_load_col_left">Load the articles in bucle</div>
    <div id="articulos_load_col_right"></div>
</div>
```